# Applying filter to read emails from multiple SenderEmailAddress in win32com

Tags: python, outlook, outlook-object-model

I am trying to read emails received from specific email addresses (more than 1). For single use case, the following code seems to be working -

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'abc@xyz.com' ")
```

For providing multiple email ID as a filter I tried the following two approaches but that does not work -

```
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'abc@xyz.com; mno@xyz.com' ")
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] In ['abc@xyz.com', 'mno@xyz.com'] ")
```

How can I provide multiple filter values like in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include multiple conditions using the `OR` operator:

```
" ([SenderEmailAddress] = 'abc@xyz.com' ) or ([SenderEmailAddress] = 'mno@xyz.com') "
```

Comment: Wait, what, win32com allows to filter outlook received mails ?